# Como armazenar os dados vindo do Arduino numa string Java?

Tags: java, arduino, serial

Preciso armazenar dados vindo do `Arduino` no `Java` via comunicação serial só que os valores a vezes não preenchido por completo. estou usando a biblioteca `rxtx`.

```
      //trecho do código para leitura
                    int available = input.available();
                    byte chunk[] = new byte[available];
                    input.read(chunk, 0, available);
                    output.write(0);
                    output.flush(); 
     String teste = new String(chunk); 
 System.out.println(teste);
 close();//fecha comunicação serial
```

Do `Arduino` envia os dados assim `@678&`,
Mas avezes o `Java` armazena assim `@6, 7, 8&, etc` ou seja pega só um pedaço.

Comment: Provavelmente isso acontece porque o loop no Java executa mais rápido que o tempo que leva para transmitir toda a informação. Ou seja, cada vez que executa, apenas um trecho da informação está no buffer. O que pode fazer é definir um caractere que indica o final da informação e enquanto o Java não ler este caractere, concatena a informação que chegou com a anterior.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss valeu pela dica, eu tinha pensado nisso mas não tinha ideia de como implementar, acho que agora sei como fazer

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você poderia dar exemplo de como fazer isso ,não estou conseguindo

Comment: Não sei se tenho conhecimento de Java para tal. Desculpe-me. Mas talvez alguém que tenha possa fazer lendo os comentários acima.

Comment: Só com a secção acima é impossivel produzir uma resposta fiável, mas não precisa reinventar a roda.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java

A sample code faz exactamente o que pretende, apenas terá que adaptar ao código ou editar a pergunta para que seja possível enquadrar a solução.

Comment: Ao se trabalhar com a RxTx, podem ocorrer erros ao montar e desmontar strings, pegar caracter a caracter, problemas de perda de informação durante o envio ou por causa do loop do Arduino como disse o @AndersonCarlosWoss. Tente usar o Javino, que tem duas bibliotecas, uma para o Arduino e outra para o Java e permite fazer essa sincronização através de 3 modos de operação. Além disso, termina com aquele problema das bibliotecas (dll) pra quem usa windows. Então vou deixar essa sugestão que ajuda a controlar o fluxo de envio de informação de controladores para o Java e vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

O maior problema no caso não é obter os dados vindo do Arduino mas sim como controlar melhor o fluxo da comunicação serial. **O sistema é crítico o suficiente que não possa esperar 1s para encaminhar o próximo dado?** É importante saber ele precisa ser o mais real time possível para pensar também no consumo de energia.

- Se sim, concatene os inputs enviadas pelo Arduino

Note que os dados estão se "perdendo" porque enquanto Java está processando o Arduino está submetendo vários dados e isso fará mais processamento ainda.

Neste caso é necessário marcadores de início e fim para saber quando a informação chegou ao fim. Supondo que "@" e "&" são seus caracteres marcadores:

```
    int available = input.available();
    byte chunk[] = new byte[available];
    input.read(chunk, 0, available);
    output.write(0);
    output.flush();
    String teste = new String(chunk);
    String dado = "";
    if("@".equals(teste)){
        //Limpar lixo de dado anterior 
        dado = "";
    }else if(teste.contains("@") && teste.contains("&")){
        //Dado foi pego por completo
        dado = teste;
    }else{
        if(teste.contains("@")){
            dado += teste.replaceAll("@", "");
        }else if("&".equals(teste)){
            //Dado foi pego por completo. 
            //A partir daqui pode realizar operações como salvar no BD, tratar dado etc
        }else if(teste.contains("&")){
            dado += teste.replaceAll("&", "");
        }
    }
```

- Se não, sugiro utilizar no código do Arduino as funções *delay* ou *sleep*